# I cannot see any data stored via Application.persistentDataPath

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm building an AR app that takes a picture of the AR camera and uses it for machine learning.

Now I want to save and view this AR Camera image for debugging.

To simplify this, I have written a script that simply creates and saves a txt:

```
    public class Save_Image_Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshPro debugText;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SaveTextToFile("Hello, World!", "testFile.txt");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves a text string to a file in the application's persistent data path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textToSave">The text string to save.</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">The name of the file to save the text in.</param>
    public void SaveTextToFile(string textToSave, string fileName)
    {
        // Construct the full path where the file will be saved.
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, fileName);

        // Use StreamWriter to write the text to a file.
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, false))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(textToSave);
                debugText.text = ($"Successfully saved to {fullPath}");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            debugText.text = ($"Failed to save to {fullPath} with exception {ex}");
        }
    }
}
```

I have connected my cell phone to my PC (USB for data transfer) and am looking for the folder there.
Unfortunately, I can't see this folder on my PC.

My debug text even tells me that the image was successfully saved under the path "/storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.XXXX".

Unity 2021.3.36
(AR Foundation
AR Core)
Android 14

Comment: Further you did not tell how you tried to see that folder.

Comment: @blackapps edit, I hope you can help me out here now :-)

Comment: You are talking about an android subfolder but it should be Android. Do you see this Android folder?

Comment: And with Android Studio there is a Device Explorer. You better use something like that in your IDE.

Comment: Yes, I see "internal storage - android - data" and all apps starting with "com.".
But not my app.

Comment: @blackapps
I can actually get to the "files" folder with Android Studio

So: /data/data/com.CompanyName.AppName/files

But the folder is empty.

Comment: But that is quite a different path then the one you mentioned in your post. Unclear why you do that.

Comment: `I see "internal storage - android - data` Bad. Use a better file explorer/manager. One that shows real full path /storage/emulated/0/Android/data.